# How to replace 'nested for loop' with tf.map_fun or tf.data.Dataset.map

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

This snippet is part of yolo detection algorithm, and I have tensorflow 1.14 environment.

When executed this part of code throws error and expected to apply tf.map_fn,

But i have nested for loop in this, how to replace nested for loop with map functions. How to
pass multiple iterators in map functions.

Test data is as below.

```
N = 2
j = 3

# y_true: (N, j, (x1, y1, x2, y2, class, best_anchor))
y_true = np.array([[[0.44839415, 0.59263945, 0.03721865, 0.03807094, 7.,0.]]])

# anchor_idx: (1, 1, 1)
anchor_idxs = np.array([[[2]]])

grid_size = 13
```

below is the snippet

```
indexes = tf.TensorArray(tf.int32, 1, dynamic_size=True)
updates = tf.TensorArray(tf.float32, 1, dynamic_size=True)
idx = 0

for i in tf.range(N):
    for j in tf.range(tf.shape(y_true)[1]):
        if tf.equal(y_true[i][j][2], 0):
            continue
        anchor_eq = tf.equal(
            anchor_idxs, tf.cast(y_true[i][j][5], tf.int32))

        if tf.reduce_any(anchor_eq):
            box = y_true[i][j][0:4]
            box_xy = (y_true[i][j][0:2]

            anchor_idx = tf.cast(tf.where(anchor_eq), tf.int32)
            grid_xy = tf.cast(box_xy // (1/grid_size), tf.int32)

            # grid[y][x][anchor] = (tx, ty, bw, bh, obj, class)
            indexes = indexes.write(
                idx, [i, grid_xy[1], grid_xy[0], anchor_idx[0][0]])
            updates = updates.write(
                idx, [box[0], box[1], box[2], box[3], 1, y_true[i][j][4]])
            idx += 1
```

when executing this I'm getting

TypeError: Tensor objects are not iterable when eager execution is not enabled. To iterate over this tensor use tf.map_fn.

How to supplement this nested for loop with tf.map_fn or tf.data.Dataset.map
Thank you

Comment: you can also use `tf.while_loop`, [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/while_loop)

Comment: Thank you, I used ```tf.while_loop```, and it worked.